# How to support jsonp in modern spring applications

Tags: spring-boot, java-17

I have a spring6 application that needs to support jsonp. It's legacy and we want to contune supporting it for now. I had migrated this application from an older version of spring that still supported jsonp but the new version doesn't so I added a JsonpMappingJacksonValue class and a AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice class into my project. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working as I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonValue cannot be cast to class com.webapp.controller.advice.JsonpMappingJacksonValue (org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonValue and com.webapp.controller.advice.JsonpMappingJacksonValue are in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader
```

This is what my JsonpMappingJacksonValue looks like:

```
package com.webapp.controller.advice;

import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonValue;

public class JsonpMappingJacksonValue extends MappingJacksonValue {
    private String jsonpFunction;

    public JsonpMappingJacksonValue(Object value) {
        super(value);
    }

    public void setJsonpFunction(String functionName) {
        this.jsonpFunction = functionName;
    }

    public String getJsonpFunction() {
        return this.jsonpFunction;
    }
}
```

and this is what AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice looks like:

```
package com.webapp.controller.advice;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.core.MethodParameter;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonValue;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMappingJacksonResponseBodyAdvice;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice extends AbstractMappingJacksonResponseBodyAdvice {
/**
 * Pattern for validating jsonp callback parameter values.
 */
private static final Pattern CALLBACK_PARAM_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[0-9A-Za-z_\\.]*");


private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

private final String[] jsonpQueryParamNames;


protected AbstractJsonpResponseBodyAdvice(String... queryParamNames) {
    Assert.isTrue(!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(queryParamNames), "At least one query param name is required");
    this.jsonpQueryParamNames = queryParamNames;
}

@Override
protected void beforeBodyWriteInternal(MappingJacksonValue bodyContainer, MediaType contentType, MethodParameter returnType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
    HttpServletRequest servletRequest = ((ServletServerHttpRequest) request).getServletRequest();
    JsonpMappingJacksonValue jsonpBodyContainer = (JsonpMappingJacksonValue) bodyContainer;

    for (String name : this.jsonpQueryParamNames) {
        String value = servletRequest.getParameter(name);
        if (value != null) {
            if (!isValidJsonpQueryParam(value)) {
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("Ignoring invalid jsonp parameter value: " + value);
                }
                continue;
            }
            MediaType contentTypeToUse = getContentType(contentType, request, response);
            response.getHeaders().setContentType(contentTypeToUse);
            jsonpBodyContainer.setJsonpFunction(value);
            break;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Validate the jsonp query parameter value. The default implementation
 * returns true if it consists of digits, letters, or "_" and ".".
 * Invalid parameter values are ignored.
 * @param value the query param value, never {@code null}
 * @since 4.1.8
 */
protected boolean isValidJsonpQueryParam(String value) {
    return CALLBACK_PARAM_PATTERN.matcher(value).matches();
}

/**
 * Return the content type to set the response to.
 * This implementation always returns "application.properties/javascript".
 * @param contentType the content type selected through content negotiation
 * @param request the current request
 * @param response the current response
 * @return the content type to set the response to
 */
protected MediaType getContentType(MediaType contentType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
    return new MediaType("application.properties", "javascript");
}
}
```

So I'm not sure how to fix this as my JsonMappingJacksonValue class is properly extending MappingJacksonValue. I'm wondering if my folder structure is the problem? This is all within my projects folder under webapp/controller/advice but MappingJacksonValue is from springframework. Can someone help me figure out how to get this working?